# Twitter streaming api - OAuth signature confusion

Tags: api, twitter, streaming

I'm working on an app and a part of it is to get the tweets of the user logged into this app. I created an app on Twitter and I generated an OAuth signature for the User stream API (https://userstream.twitter.com/2/user.json). I ran the curl command generated and made a couple tweets. I was able to see those in real time. My question now is that if someone else was logged in, would they be able to run the exact same curl command (or the exact same GET request) and see their tweets? If not, how would I generate an OAuth signature for them to see their tweets?

Answer (score 0):

A user stream returns content for the authenticated user. So, if another user performs the authentication, Twitter will know who they are and return their content.

Comment: So it's sufficient for me to generate an OAuth signature for the app I created, and through that signature any logged in user will be able to see his/her tweets?

Comment: Can't use the same signature more than once because of the timestamp, nonce, and possibly different parameters. Also, the user_token and access_token are unique to each individual.  Each user will have to authenticate at least one time and then you can save their oauth_token and access_token for all subsequent requests by that user (consumer_key and consumer_secret are always the same because they belong to your app). Look at what data is included (at this link), which demonstrates why you can't reuse a signature: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature